# Regex: Find lines that NOT contains curly brackets

Tags: regex, windows, notepad++

good day. I want to select only the lines that NOT contain `}}` or `);` or `){` but that DO contain a `(`

In this example, I want to match only the line starting with `php is` that has a simple open `(` parenthesis

> php is (the most open...
>
> EmbedManager.embed({  key:
>   "https://fs2.formsite.com/res/showFormEmbed?EParam=m%2FOmK8apOTAL%2BJ4ksjDS9NNt7h1SghSJ6&1919401971",
>     width: "100%",  mobileResponsive: true });
>
> make (home) edition 32 https://s..

I make an regex, but does not work too good because it selects also the first bracket from the first line:

`^[^(\r\n]*\K\)(?!;)(?![\}])(?![\{])|\((?!(?-s).*\))`

Comment: If you want to see lines which DON'T contain …, you might use `grep -v ...`.

Comment: Why is your regex like this? What are the pattern requirements?

Comment: `make (home) edition 32 https://s..` should also be included according to your definition. It doesn't contain the pair of characters you like to exclude. Your requirements are incomplete or your example is incorrect.

Comment: it is just an example. I need to find only the line that contains a simple open breaket `(`, not those lines that contains `}}` or `);` or `){`. In my case, the last line I want to match

Comment: What is it? Only lines containing a simple open bracket **and** not containing  `}}`, `);`, `){`? You should edit your question and add your **exact** requirements. From your comments, the `make (home)...`still should match

Answer (score 2):

You may do a replacement of the non matching lines, and replace them with nothing.  Try doing a find:

```
^(?=.*(\}\}|\);|\)\{))(?!.*\().*$
```

And then replace with nothing.

This should leave behind the lines you want to see.

If you instead want to just highlight/toggle the matching lines, then you may rephrase the above regex to use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*(\}\}|\);|\)\{))(?=.*\().*$
```

This would match the lines you want to see.

### Demo

Comment: nope, is not working. And I have to find in 200 html pages, so I don't want to replace nothing, just searching

Comment: @RobRob My pattern had a slight problem, but it's fixed now.

Comment: hello, Tim, your regex in your example, indeed the lines that NOT contains `}}` or `);` or `){`  BUT, in my example doesn't work. AND I need regex to find also the line staring with php that has an open breaket `(`

Comment: Then add `php (` to the start of the pattern.  Your requirements keep changing.

Comment: I think I was misunderstood :)

Comment: @RobRob I updated my answer to also check for an opening parenthesis.

Comment: @Tim - that also matches the `make (home)..`. From comments, OP mentioned that should not be matched.

Comment: Yes, and based on the requirements that should match.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Yes but the requirements shift with every comment and edit we make...

Comment: I'm going by the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I FIND THE ANSWER ! Evrika !!

FIND:

`\((?!.*[()]).*$`

or

`\((?!.*[\)]).*$`

or

`^[^(\r\n]*\K\)(?!;)(?![\}])(?![\{])|\((?!.*[\{]).*$`